# Autenticar Usuario con Unit Test

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

Estoy haciendo pruebas unitarias en **Laravel 5.7** y específicamente cuando hago el test para autenticar un usuario, la prueba nunca pasa, aquí mi código:

```
/** @test */
public function autenticandoUnUsuario()
{

    $user = User::where('email', 'test@test.com')->first();
    $this->get('/login')->assertSee('Log in');
    $credentials = [
        "email" => $user->email,
        "password" => $user->password
    ];

    $response = $this->post('/login', $credentials);
    $response->assertRedirect('/bienvenido');
    $this->assertCredentials($credentials);
}
```

El error que me da PHPUnit es este:

> F                                                                   1
>   / 1 (100%)
>
> Time: 1.47 seconds, Memory: 16.00MB
>
> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) Tests\Unit\LoginTest::autenticandoUnUsuario Response status code
>   [419] is not a redirect status code. Failed asserting that false is
>   true.
>
> /home/vagrant/Projects/mynewproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/T
>   /home/vagrant/Projects/mynewproject/tests/Unit/LoginTest.php:40
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.

Las credenciales son la correctas, debería pasar la prueba. Cuando comento la linea 45 que seria esta:

```
$response->assertRedirect('/bienvenido');
```

El error que muestra PHPUnit es otro:

> F                                                                   1
>   / 1 (100%)
>
> Time: 2.16 seconds, Memory: 16.00MB
>
> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) Tests\Unit\LoginTest::autenticandoUnUsuario The given credentials
>   are invalid. Failed asserting that false is true.
>
> /home/vagrant/Projects/mynewproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithAuthentication.php:114
>   /home/vagrant/Projects/mynewproject/tests/Unit/LoginTest.php:41
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.

Intenta validar pero dice que las credenciales no son validas cuando en realidad si lo son, inicio sesion y todo funciona ok.

P.D.: Laravel 5.7 tiene 2 carpetas en `/tests` que son `/Feature` y `/Unit` mis pruebas se están guardando en `Unit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente los passwords en Laravel se almacenan con un hash, no en el texto plano que uno escribe en el formulario de inicio de sesión.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, cuando tomas el usuario de la base de datos y tomas su campo password, estás tomando una cadena con el hash ya aplicado:

```
$user = User::where('email', 'test@test.com')->first();

$credentials = [
    "email" => $user->email,
    "password" => $user->password
];
```

Al enviar el post con el password con el hash no te va a funcionar porque en vez de enviar `micontrasena`, estás enviando algo como `$2y$10$ApNVfRmhSWwBQ2oAyt5pueDShW0bZmSK121J2Re/rJZfgB`.

**No hay forma de reversar el proceso después de aplicar el hash a la contraseña, por lo cual tendrás que buscar otra forma de enviar la contraseña, distinta a obtenerla de la base de datos.**

Comment: Gracias @Shaz modifique el password y lo escribí directamente y la Prueba paso correctamente y valido las credenciales, gracias por tu respuesta